# Getting a object name

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get a object name in javascipt

```
 lov_DgId_D_2.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick= DgIdOnClick(???????????);
```

I got a spanid which I add onclick event now i want to get/extract this id 'lov_DgId_D_2' like name and put as argument to function DgIdOnClick.

Priview:

```
 lov_DgId_D_2.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick= DgIdOnClick('lov_DgId_D_2');
 lov_DgId_D_3.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick= DgIdOnClick('lov_DgId_D_3');
 lov_DgId_D_4.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick= DgIdOnClick('lov_DgId_D_4');
```

U.t.c 
But not so simple to write it name in argument.
THANKS! ;)

Comment: could you show some code (a little jsfiddle would be perfect) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Plain Javascript

I would recommend using an anonymous function as event handler.

```
lov_DgId_D_2.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick = function (event) {
  DgIdOnClick(this.id);
}
```

Note: In this case, the `this` keyword refers to the clicked HTML Element. But maybe you want to use `event.target.id` instead of `this.id`.

#### Javascript using jQuery framework

Since you have tagged your question with jQuery, I assume you implemented it in your project and would be pleased to hear a clean and simple solution using jQuery.

```
$('a', lov_DgId_D_2).click(function () {
  DgIdOnClick(this.id);
}
```